# Preserve Current Paths before rolling out new Pathauto Alias

Tags: 6, redirection, path-aliases

I'm just about to roll out a new Pathauto Alias to include a new taxonomy term, which will modify about 1000 nodes. Is there a way to preserve the current path aliases I have now, and then bulk update all my nodes to the new pattern?

I assume I'll need to use Path Redirect in conjunction with Global Redirect somehow to keep the old paths pointing to the new paths?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve AND redirect existing aliases when you implement a change like that:

- install the Path Redirect module
- open the 'Automated Alias Settings' in URL Aliases (admin/build/path/pathauto)
- open the 'General' fieldset
- change the radio button for 'Update action' to 'Create a new alias. Redirect from old alias' (see screenshot below).

http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/2738/redirectaliasleaveintac.png

Comment: No problem. That option is seriously hard to find!

Comment: What's the easiest way to bulk generate the new paths? (or for that matter, any way, without deleting existing :)

Comment: I think Views Bulk Operations is the easiest way. It allows you to update as many URLs as your server memory permits.

Comment: Oh awesome, I'd always ignored VBO, never realised this is what it was for :D Thanks again!